How to run Anaconda environment on IIS with WFASTCGI?
I have developed a web application in Python using the bottle framework.
I have a Windows Server, and I used IIS as Web Server for my application, using WFASTCGI.
My application requires packages to be installed with Anaconda.
I configured by handler as follows:
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="Python FastCGI"
       path="*"
       verb="*"
       modules="FastCgiModule"
       scriptProcessor="C:\path_to_my_env\python.exe|C:\path_to_my_env\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"
       resourceType="Unspecified"
       requireAccess="Script" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>

This works fine, but I am now asked to migrate on a new server.
So, I installed a recent version of anaconda, but unfortunately executing directly the python in the environment folder is not sufficient anymore. I need to activate the python environment beforehand.
However, I do not know how to do this with WFASTCGI.
Has anyone managed to do this?

The entire virtual environment design wasn’t well suited on Windows as far as I tested. So hard to imagine there is a way out. Linux isn’t an option for you?

@LexLi managed to make it work perfectly with previous versions of Conda. This is why it is so frustrating. If I can get IIS to run a .bat before calling the server app, that would work. Don't you think that doable with HttpPlatformHandler? Something similar to what you suggested here?

I didn't get any success with virtual environments. That's why my posts all show how to configure with the interpreters globally.
